# Set Closed or Open

Tags: general-topology

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $ with the Euclidean metric. $E$ is defined as follows 
$$E = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x \geq 0 \land y \leq 1\}$$

Is this set open, closed, both, or neither.

I think this set is closed, but I'm not sure. Any guidance would help

Comment: Have you drawn a picture? Not that a picture contains the answer completely (in fact, it certainly does not in this case).

Comment: Please provide an attempt using the definitions of a closed and open set.

Comment: Sorry about the late edit, it removed your attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$E=({[0,+\infty [}\cap\mathbb Q)\times ({]-\infty ,1]}\cap \mathbb Q).$$

By density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$, there is $\{(x_n,y_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset E$ s.t. $(x_n,y_n)\to (\pi, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2})\notin E$ and thus it's not closed. To prove that it's not open, the interior is simply empty... (the interior of any subset of $\mathbb Q$ is always empty)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the only open set in $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is the empty set? And on $E$ is only closed if it is finite?

Comment: I hope it's more clear.

Comment: there are infinite subsets of $\Bbb Q^2$ that are closed.....

Comment: @mercio: Yes of course. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: $R^2\backslash Q^2$ is dense in  $R^2$  because if $ V\subset R^2 $ is  open and not empty then $V\supset (a,b)\times (c,d)$  for some $a<b$ and $c<d.$ So for any irrational $x,y$   with $x\in (a,b)$ and $y\in (c,d),$  you have $(x,y)\in V$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $q$ be a number in $\mathbb{Q}$. Then for any $r>0$ we have that $B(q,r)$ contains both rationals and irrationals by the density properties of both. Thus $B(q,r) \not \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ and so $\mathbb{Q}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$. By similar logic we find that the irrationals are not open and so $\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. (remember that the set of irrationals is the complement of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$)

Extend this argument to $\mathbb{R^2}$ and you will be well on your way to showing that $E$ is neither open nor closed.

Comment: obviously the ball in $\mathbb{R}$ is simply the open interval.

Answer (score 1):

E is not open - for E to be open, every point of E must be enclosed in a open set (neighborhood) contained in E,  pick any point on x=0, then there is no open set G which is entirely contained in E and contains x, that is any open set G will contain points outside E.  ( same argument for any rational pair (p,q) of E, any open set around (p,q) will contain irrational numbers, so E not open). ( also explains why the only open set of Q2 is the empty set).

E is not closed - if E is closed, then the complement E' would be open - but this is not possible, pick a point (irx,iry) where irx and iry are irrational numbers in the region x>=0 and y<=1, then any open neighborhood of (irx,iry) would also contain rational points (p,q),  so there is no open neighborhood of (irx,iry) which is contained entirely within E', hence E' not open, E is not closed.